# creating comboboxes inside jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

My aim is to provide an interface like a matrix, each cell in matrix will have 2 values and user will select best among the two.

So i thought of going for jTable and combo boxes, the problem is in my matrix the value of each cell in a column is different. But the following code that adds the combo box to whole column of the table and if i change the combo box value, it changes for the whole table. How to insert combo boxes into the table such that each one has different values

```
javax.swing.JComboBox k = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        k.addItem("1");
        k.addItem("2");
        k.addItem("3");
        k.setEnabled(true);
        k.setVisible(true);
this.jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(k));
```

I also tried with DefaultTableModel

code is

```
  DefaultTableModel t =new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
    t.setColumnCount(10);
    t.setRowCount(10);
    t.setValueAt(k, 0, 0);
 jTable1.setModel(t);
```

but i get the output in the gui as

```
javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777544,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=1]
```

I tried typecasting "k" as JComboBox and JComponent in setValueAt method, which didn't work

Someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Override the getCellEditor(....) method. For example: [How to add unique JComboBoxes to a column in a JTable (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211452/how-to-add-unique-jcomboboxes-to-a-column-in-a-jtable-java/4211552#4211552)

Comment: that was very useful but it doesn't seem to work properly when there were more than one column into which i have to add the combo boxes.. how to set specific combo boxes in each column too?