# Set a different combo box as cell content for each row within table column

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, jcombobox

I am creating a `JTable` in Java and I am iterating over a list called `methodtraces2`, for columns 10, 11, 12 and 13, I would like each cell to be made of a `JComboBox`. For example, each cell within column 10 should contain a combo box and each row within the combo box should contain one entry within the list `methodtrace.getCallersList()`, each cell within column 10 would be different depending on the content of `methodtrace.getCallersList()`, which is different for every iteration of `methodtraces2`.

I am taking all the values for each combo box and storing them within the array of `String items1`, which represents the content of the combo box for each row of the table (each iteration of `methodtraces2`).

- `items1` should populate `comboBox1` at each iteration of `methodtraces2`
- `items2` should populate `comboBox2`
- `items3` should populate `comboBox3`
- `items4` should populate `comboBox4`

I need to do the same thing for columns 11, 12 and 13.

- `items2` contains the values of the combo box for column 11
- `items3` contains the values of the combo box for column 12
- `items4` contains the values of the combo box for each row within column 14.

The method `getCellEditor` is responsible for assigning combo boxes to the appropriate columns, right now, I have the same combo box content input for all the rows within column 10.

```
 public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JFrame
{
List<TableCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableCellEditor>(4);
static List<MethodTrace2> methodtraces2= new ArrayList<MethodTrace2>(); 


public TableComboBoxByRow() throws SQLException
{
    DatabaseReading2 db = new DatabaseReading2(); 
    DatabaseReading2.MakePredictions();
    methodtraces2= db.getMethodtraces2(); 
    int j=0; 
    String[] items1 = new String [methodtraces2.size()]; 
    String[] items2 = new String [methodtraces2.size()]; 
    String[] items3 = new String [methodtraces2.size()]; 
    String[] items4 = new String [methodtraces2.size()]; 
 Object[][] data = new Object[methodtraces2.size()][10000]; 
    // Create the editors to be used for each row
    for(MethodTrace2 methodtrace: methodtraces2) {
        data[j][0]= methodtrace.MethodRepresentation.getMethodid(); 
        data[j][1]= methodtrace.MethodRepresentation.getMethodname(); 
        data[j][2]= methodtrace.Requirement.getID(); 
        data[j][3]= methodtrace.Requirement.getRequirementName(); 
        data[j][4]= methodtrace.ClassRepresentation.classid; 
        data[j][5]= methodtrace.ClassRepresentation.classname; 
        data[j][6]= methodtrace.gold; 
        data[j][7]= methodtrace.subject; 
        data[j][8]= methodtrace.goldpredictionCaller; 
        data[j][9]= methodtrace.goldpredictionCallee; 

        int i=0; 
        items1 = new String[methodtrace.getCallersList().size()]; 
         for(Method2Representation caller: methodtrace.getCallersList()) {
              items1[i]=caller.toString(); 
              System.out.println(caller.toString());
              i++; 

          }
        // data[j][10]=items1; 
         int k=0; 
         items2 = new String[ methodtrace.getCalleesList().size()]; 
         for(Method2Representation caller: methodtrace.getCalleesList()) {
              items2[k]=caller.toString(); 
              System.out.println(caller.toString());
              k++; 

          }
         int r=0; 
         items3 = new String[methodtrace.getCallersListExecuted().size()]; 
         for(Method2Representation caller: methodtrace.getCallersListExecuted()) {
              items3[r]=caller.toString(); 
              System.out.println(caller.toString());
              r++; 

          }
         int z=0; 
         items4 = new String[10000]; 
         for(Method2Representation caller: methodtrace.getCalleesListExecuted()) {
              items4[z]=caller.toString(); 
              System.out.println(caller.toString());
              z++; 

          }




            JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox( items1 );
            DefaultCellEditor dce1 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
            editors.add( dce1 );

            JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox( items2 );
            DefaultCellEditor dce2 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox2 );
            editors.add( dce2 );


            JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox( items3 );
            DefaultCellEditor dce3 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox3 );
            editors.add( dce3 );


            JComboBox comboBox4 = new JComboBox( items4);
            DefaultCellEditor dce4 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox4 );
            editors.add( dce4 );



         j++; 
    }






    String[] columnNames = {"MethodID","MethodName", "RequirementID", "RequirementName", "ClassID", "ClassName", "Gold", "Subject", "GoldPredictionCaller", "GoldPredictionCallee", 
            "Callers", "CallersExecuted", "Callees", "CalleesExecuted"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable table = new JTable(model)
    {
        //  Determine editor to be used by row
        public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
        {
            int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

            if (modelColumn == 10 && row < methodtraces2.size())
                return editors.get(0);

            else
                return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
        }
    };
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(10).setWidth(10000);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
    getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
}



class ComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer
{

    public ComboBoxRenderer()
    {
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        removeAllItems();
        addItem( value );
        return this;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
{

    TableComboBoxByRow frame = new TableComboBoxByRow();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: After editing & reformatting that wall of text, I still see no question. What is your question?

Comment: Maybe this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211452/how-to-add-unique-jcomboboxes-to-a-column-in-a-jtable-java/4211552#4211552 will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand what is going on here, but you mentioned that you are iterating over a list called **methodtraces2** however in the code you posted:

```
 for(Method2Representation caller: methodtrace (NOT methodtrace2!).getCallersList()) {
    items1[i]=caller.toString(); 
    System.out.println(caller.toString());
    i++; 

  }
```

You are in fact iterating over methodTrace (note: not methodTraces2). An additional thing to try when debugging these kinds of problems is to simplify such that:

```
 for(Method2Representation caller: methodtrace.getCallersList()) {
    items1[i]=caller.toString(); 
    System.out.println(caller.toString());
    i++; 

  }
```

can be changed to something like:

```
 String stuff[] = {"1", "2", "3", .... "N"};
 for(String s : stuff) {
    items1[i]=s
    System.out.println("testing items1[" + i + "]: " + items[i]);
    i++; 
  }
```

A final note, I hope you are changing the variable names to protect some proprietary code because those variable names will end up driving anyone mad! Use descriptive variable names, instead of items1, use callers or items2 use callees.

HH :)

Comment: I have justa added the entire code and I put more descriptive text to make you understand more the problem