# How to add different combobox to a cell

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a combobox which I am filling with database query, my combo box must be different for each row, but when adding it, it shows me the combo box with the same data for all.

I add it with this method

```
CComboBox priceListVersionComboBox = new CComboBox(priceListVersion);
TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN_PRICELIST);
col.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(priceListVersionComboBox));
```

My **ComboBox** It is filled by

```
KeyNamePair[] priceListVersion = getMPriceListVersion((Integer)table.getValueAt(i, COLUMN_PRODUCTID));
```

How do I add the value of the current combobox per row and the previous ones keep them?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211452/how-to-add-unique-jcomboboxes-to-a-column-in-a-jtable-java/4211552#4211552 for one approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add unique JComboBoxes to a column in a JTable (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211452/how-to-add-unique-jcomboboxes-to-a-column-in-a-jtable-java)

Comment: No, it's not the same.

There are different comboboxes created, I have a single combo box for many rows and I need that for each one depends on the row I have a specific value