# Populate and empty ONLY the JComboBox of the selected row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jython, jcombobox

I have a JTable with 4 columns and two JComboBoxes (Respectively on the first and second columns.).
The values of a JComboBox in the second column are filtered based on the selection of a value in the first column **only on the same row**.
The moment in which the emptying and restocking takes place is on the selection of the value of the first column.
The reciprocal setting is set up in this way:

```
self.fcaOrdinati.combo.addActionListener(self.filterFca)
self.fcaCombo = JComboBox([])
self.fcaOrdinati.mainTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(DefaultCellEditor(self.fcaCombo))
```

Below there's the listener (which works and is triggered) with the retrieval of the selected row and the value of the first JComboBox (so up to here everything is ok)

```
def filterFca(self, e):
   selectedArt = self.fcaOrdinati.combo.getSelectedItem()
   selectedRow = self.fcaOrdinati.mainTable.getSelectedRow()
   """
      ??? How do I add items only to the JComboBox of this row ???
   """
```

So my question is... How do I add items only to the JComboBox of the selected row?? (I already know the column index, so it is a constant)
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I also accept answers in Java, not just in jython.
 The number of rows in the table is not fixed. The user chooses how many to add.

Comment: By default the same editor is used by the entire column. If you want a different editor for each row in a given column then check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4211552/131872 for one approach.